# How do I change the Bulk Action buttons on the top right of the Case List View page in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, quickaction, case-object

I've been trying to figure this out all day. All I want to do is add a Delete button to the top right of my Cases list views so that people can select multiple cases and delete them. How do I change the buttons that are displayed here in LE?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard "delete" button to add to list views ([see this idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqczAAC)) so this would only work if you have a custom button.

If you do have a custom button, there's a [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&mode=1&id=000331581) that contains steps for customizing this for [standard objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_searchlayout.htm&type=5) and [custom objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizing_search_layouts.htm&type=5).

What you want to edit is the **Search Layouts** for the given object.

1. Setup
2. Object Manager
3. Select your object - in your situation "Case"

[image]

4. Add your custom button

[image]